# Dynamic Filter with dplyr R doesn't work

Tags: r

```
cols <- data %>% names()
data %>% dplyr::filter_(is.na(cols[1]))
```

gives zero although it should output some rows, alternatively when calling

```
data %>% dplyr::filter(is.na("colName"))
```

output rows

Thus, dynamic filtration not working, any idea what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dplyr::filter(data, is.na(data[, cols[1]]))
```